# How to know if NSData finished downloading to trigger a method

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am working on plotting markers on a Map, for each marker I need to download a specific image from an URL, obviously I need to do this async, but I need to know when the download is finished before triggering `addMarkerToMap ()`, otherwise the app will crash because `NSData == nil`.

I've tried using blocks, but the `completion` or `success` response is sent before the download is finished. I also tried with NSURLSessionDelegate but the Delegate methods are never called.

If someone can help me or at least guide me to a posible way to accomplish this.

thanks,

**EDIT**

Here is the last code I tried, no error is getting print and `addMarkerToMap(data)` is not being called:

```
func downloadImageFromURL () {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession (configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(self.markerURL!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if ((error != nil)) {
                    self.addMarkerToMap (data)
                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            })

    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Then people can help you get the code fixed.

Comment: Yes, please add some code. By definition completion handlers should not be called until the data is available. You either trigger an error (and the data will never be loaded), or you're then doing something wrong with the received data.

Comment: Done, I added the last code I tried. Thanks. @rmaddy

Comment: Edit done, thanks in advance @jcaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `resume()`, otherwise the task will never complete.

And like @vadian said, you must rewrite to `if ((error == nil))` or your app may find `nil` while unwrapping the data value which is optional and crash.

So, it will be like this:

```
func downloadImageFromURL () {
  let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  let session = NSURLSession (configuration: config)
  let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(self.markerURL!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        self.addMarkerToMap(data)
      } else {
        print(error)
      }
    })
  }
  task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The `error == nil` was a mistake when I wrote the question, what fixed it was the `task.resume()`. Thanks a lot Wallace

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be `if error == nil` or

```
if error != nil {
  print(error!)
} else {
  self.addMarkerToMap(data!)
}
```